# Forming Json using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I am trying to form the below json using gson.

```
  visitors  : [
                ['01/2015', 1500],
                ['02/2015', 2500],
                ['03/2015', 1700],
                ['04/2015', 900],
                ['05/2015', 1500],
                ['06/2015', 2350],
                ['07/2015', 1500],
                ['08/2015', 1300],
                ['09/2015', 4600]
            ]
```

I dont know how to do this,can anyone help me

Comment: Can you share the code sample where you tried forming the mentioned JSON?

Comment: the text you've posted is not a valid JSON format

Answer (score 0):

For tasks like these you can use a web utility like [Convert XML or JSON to JAVA POJO](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/)

Following is what I got for your JSON.

```
public class MyPojo
{
    private String[][] visitors;

    public String[][] getVisitors ()
    {
        return visitors;
    }

    public void setVisitors (String[][] visitors)
    {
        this.visitors = visitors;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [visitors = "+visitors+"]";
    }
}
```

If your java object is in the above format it should be converted to JSON correctly.

Comment: Generally the library call is not a tough part and anyone using a library can get his hands on sample code. The tougher part is to figure out the input in this case the java object which will convert to expected json correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Your json is not a valid one.

> {
>       "visitors": [
>           [
>               "01/2015",
>               1500
>           ],
>           [
>               "02/2015",
>               2500
>           ],
>           [
>               "03/2015",
>               1700
>           ],
>           [
>               "04/2015",
>               900
>           ],
>           [
>               "05/2015",
>               1500
>           ],
>           [
>               "06/2015",
>               2350
>           ],
>           [
>               "07/2015",
>               1500
>           ],
>           [
>               "08/2015",
>               1300
>           ],
>           [
>               "09/2015",
>               4600
>           ]
>       ] }

This json I printed is validated.
Create an object with setters and getters.as shown inthe example below

```
import java.util.*;
  public class MyObject
 {private List<List<Map<String,Integer>>>visitors;
  public void setVisitors(List<List<Map<String,Integer>>>visitors)
   {this.visitors=visitors;
    }
public List<List<Map<String,Integer>>> getVisitors()
   {return this.visitors;
    }}

public class Test{
public static void main(String arg[]){
     Type objType = new TypeToken<MyObject>() {}.getType();
     MyObject obj= new MyObject();
     ArrayList<List> outerList=new ArrayList<List>();
     ArrayList innerList=new ArrayList<Map<String,Integer>>();
     Map mp=new HashMap();
     mp.put("03/2015",1700);
     innerList.add(mp);
     outerList.add(innerList);
     obj.setVisitors(outerList);
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson(obj, objType );}}

The json now will be similar to your Json in discussion.
```